# Why does this amplifier distort a triangle wave?

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, mosfet, current

[image]

The above voltage amplifier is taken from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVLO4YBURSo&ab_channel=ElectronXLab).

I have simulated this circuit in LTspice and it works well with a sine wave input.

When I tried a triangle wave for its input, the waveform becomes bad.

Is there a circuit that can amplify any input waveform shape to 10 times its input signal without using an op-amp and still keeping the same waveform? I would prefer using discrete components such as transistors and resistors.

[image]

Comment: Remember that for a triangle, you must "pass" at least the 10th harmonic. So, if you know the bandwidth of this amplifier ... you can calculate the max frequency of the triangular at the input.

Comment: What was the frequency of the triangle wave?  What was the frequency of the sine wave?  Those three capacitors give the circuit a frequency dependent output.  The signal level also matters.  Another important point is the transistor you used.  It would be better if you posted your LTspice circuit as well as a labeled diagram of the input and output.

Comment: What’s the frequency? If no DC-offset, how about a transformer?

Comment: @greybeard why do you say that? Why would the load need to be matched to the output impedance in a simple audio type amplifier?

Comment: @jessica - it's a poor circuit for linear amplification so, if that is what you need you'd do better using an op-amp. You did the right thing using a triangle wave of course because it can "visually" expose a lot of problems related to non-linearity and bandwidth limitations.

Comment: Gain is not really what is generally used for a preamplifier (not "constant" along the "bandwidth") ... It seems for a large part to be a "differentiator" ... So, a triangle at the input should lead to a "square" at the output.

Comment: @greybeard that has nothing to do with the problem faced by jessica

Comment: Do an AC analysis in spice, that should give you the answer.

Comment: @jessica You will have to say something about the frequencies you need to support. You can see this already in the answers. If you are looking for a discrete solution, as you say, and hoping for a more specific suggestion then the frequencies are needed. Also, just to confirm: Is your source impedance 600 Ohm? Does that resistor represent your source impedance? And is your load actually 12k? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this amplifier distort a triangle wave?

The "transfer" function is not really an amplifier ... but quasi a "differentiator".

[image]

[image]

You should change the emitter capacitor to 1000 uF and base capacitor to at least 10 uF.

The bandwidth should be 10 Hz to 100 kHz.

So a 1000 Hz to 10 kHz triangular wave should be outputted without "distortion",
composite gain = ~ 200. NB: QP is "ok".

If you want a "gain" of 10, then insert a ~ 500 Ohm resistor between the emitter and the 3 kOhm // 10 uF. Should then be ok from triangular wave from ~ 300 Hz to ~ 100 kHz.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, your circuit is brilliant :), I have simulated your circuit in LT Spice, however, my input AC voltage amplitude is 0.5V and I wish to amplify the voltage as large as possible while keeping the voltage source with 9V battery , is it possible :) ? 24V is a bit too large for me and requires a lot of batteries :) , what are the modifications to resistors or even capacitor required while keeping your same bandwidth which is 10 Hz to 100 kHz  ?

Comment: I will try to plug everything into the breadboard :)

Comment: Circuit "should" work also at 9 V without change (automatic polarization). I will simulate it and say if it work.

Comment: Hi, that would mean if input is 0.5V AC triangle wave, it will output a 5V AC triangle wave right? But I have simulated your circuit with this input, but the amplification drops :(

Comment: Just change R9 to adjust gain. Note that if you will at output 5 Vpeak, you need a supply at least ~15 V. I do it interactively with microcap v12.  http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: Hi , thanks for the quick reply, so by no means we cannot lower the voltage supply any further right? So, we need to maintain in this proportion which is 15V supply for 5 Vpeak, 30V supply for 10Vpeak ?

Comment: Yes. Something like this, because some "guard" voltage must be kept (Components tolerance 5% and "large" imprecision for BJT beta vs temperature).

Answer (score 4):

It distorts the wave because you don't have enough bandwidth to pass the triangle wave and it is attenuating frequency content. You'll need to increase the bandwidth of the amplifier.

Answer (score 3):

The guy in the video ignored frequencies, shorted all capacitors and made all calculations for DC.

You said a gain of 10 times but a simulation of my fixed circuit shows a gain of 195 times but there will be severe distortion at higher levels.

One capacitor has its capacitance a few hundred times too small, look at these simulations of frequency response.
[image: transisor amplifier]

Comment: Hi, from your circuit simulation, do you know how to maximize the voltage amplification with a 9V voltage source instead of 24V because 24V is too much ? The voltage amplification output should be equal or greater than 10 times its input. My input is exactly 0.5V amplitude triangle wave :)